# Link php code to a html page

Tags: php, html, css, xampp

OK, so I have a entry form login page saved as a .php file, its content is displayed in html and css. 
It displays a few things and then a log in form with 2 fields: Username, Password and then a 'Log in' button.

I have created a separate .php file which looks like this:

```
<?php

$username = $_POST ['Username'];
$password = $_POST['Password'];

if ($username && $password)
 {

 $connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die ("couldn't connect");

 mysql_select_db("sportsday") or die ("couldn't find db");

 }

 else 
 die("Please enter a username and password");

?>
```

I believe this code is now connected to my other page (http://jsfiddle.net/6yw8a2ue/) 
It shows some errors next to the fields in browser: 
"Notice: Undefined indiex: Username in G:\xampp\htdocs\Sportsday\entryformlongon.php"...

and once i enter a username and password it goes through to blank page with the error:
"Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in G:\xampp\htdocs\Sportsday\login.php on line 11"

Comment: This `if ($username&&£$password)` - remove the `£` - `if ($username && $password)` that's where the parse error originates from. Now, what do you mean by *"How can I link this php file to the other one?"* ?

Comment: well i was following a log in tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7ae_cZahPs) and they used two separate php files and it connected fine. but for me its not

Comment: @Fred-ii- i need the code show in the screenshot to be used for my log in page basically

Comment: So, why not show us what you're using then, or is that your entire code?

Comment: I don't view YouTube videos, sorry. Do you need a form? Is that what you need, to pass information from the form to your posted code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6yw8a2ue/ this is what i am trying to connect the code above to

Comment: You're wanting to check if username and password match in DB, am I getting this right?

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide.

Comment: What's with all these *wrong* answers below? Read the question/comments `@ALL_people`.

Comment: [`This is the question where I need an answer for...`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26534018/link-php-code-to-a-html-page#comment41694453_26534018) @CharleyBaker or am I the one not grasping the question?

Comment: As per your edit, there you go; deprecated. Use `mysqli_` or PDO as the notice states. Besides that, I have no idea what you want to do. I wish you well with that, I am moving on.

Comment: ok I will use that instead.. I just trying to create users for a log in form which connects to a mysql database

Comment: Here http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Login-Script-in-PHP-and-MySQL

Comment: You have completely changed the original question so that nearly all the answers you have received are no longer relevant (as @Fred-ii- pointed out). If you have a different question you need to ask a new question rather than updating this one to the point of being unrecognizable from what was originally asked which was how to include the files correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Please look over this documentation.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

You can require the file in any page needed.

Answer (score 0):

point your form action atribute to the php file.

```
<form method="post" action="phpsubmit.php">
  form stuff
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Require at the top of the page to be included.
require 'filename';

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
exit;
```

I assume by link to other php file, you mean forward to another page once complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect to other page when fields are empty or inputs are not matching.Can simply do

```
 $username=$row["username"];
 $password=$row["password"];
 header("location:page_to_link.php?u=".$username);
 }
 else{
  header("location:page you want to redirect");
 }
```

you have to start session on the page you redirecting(linking) them by session_start().

Hope that helps

Comment: I have edited the original question, im looking for something else

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 options to include the file into the main document.

```
include
include_once
require
require_once
```

[include doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [include_once doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [require doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), [require_once doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php)

Each of these will add the code to your main file and do essentially the same thing. `include` and `require` will include the file as many times as the line of code is called (which can cause issues if you just need it called once). `include_once` and `require_once` will import the file to the document only one time regardless of whether or not that line of code is called multiple times.

A big difference between `include` and `require` lies in the type of error you will get. `include` will return a warning error if the file isn't found but your code will continue to execute (with errors). `require` will produce a fatal error which will kill the program then and there.

So if you have form.php and want to include it it would look something like this for each option.

```
include 'form.php';
include_once 'form.php';
require 'form.php';
require_once 'form.php';
```

Depending on where the document lies that you are trying to include you will need to get the correct directory first (ie if you are trying to include from from /path/file.php from /path/path/file.php). Unlike normal HTML `'/'` does not result in your site root. It results in your server root.

So if you have a file that exists at website.com/path/file.php you couldn't just do include '/path/file.php' because that would actually look for the file at the root of the server which would not exist.

To get around this you will want to utilize `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` which will then grab the root of your document from the server which might look something like the following (depending on your setup):

`/var/www/html/website.com`

And so rather than having to figure that out, you can just add the document root line to the include statements

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/file.php';
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/file.php';
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/file.php';
require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/file.php';
```

Comment: I have edited the original question

Answer (score 0):

You have forgotten to check if the form is submitted 
add the floowing in the beginning of your code:

`if(isset($_POST ['Username']) && isset($_POST ['Password'])){`

and off course, don't forget to place a close bracket at the end